# How do I export multiple variables, classes or functions at one time?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, es6-modules

I have tried to export multiple variables, classes and functions, but I keep getting an error that I have to declare it. Is there any way I can get around this? Here’s the code.

JS:

```
var exports = [];

for(var module of exports) {
   export module; //This gives me the error.
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type=“module” src=“main.js”></script>
```

Comment: What code is filling the `exports` array? Just add `export` declarations to it, instead of trying to do dynamic exports (which are impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that because you are not allowed to do that.

Add `export` to each symbol you want to export:

```js
export var a = 1;
export function f(){}
```

Or

```js
var a = 1;
function f(){}
export {
    a,
    f,
}
```